# How to calculate total quantity and total in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my cart:

[image]

The issue I'm having now is, total quantity and total not adding with new value but replacing with new value, so that it shows the last value. I want to add up the value.

This is the script to add for total quantity and total subtotal in the bottom:

```
function calTotal(param)
       {
//this carries the latest value for quantity
           var qty = $('td.qty_'+param+' input[type=text]').val();
//this carries the latest value for subtotal
           var total = $('span.sub_total_'+param+'').text();
//this shows the values respectively in the white row below
           $('span.qty_1').text(qty);
           $('span.total').text(total);
//I'm trying to add the values in localStorage but it shows in string form.
           localStorage.quantity += parseInt(qty);
           alert(localStorage.quantity);


       }
```

> //I'm trying to add the values in localStorage but it shows in string
>   form.For instance when first item's quantity key in '2' it should show
>   2. WHen next item quantity keyed in '4' it must add prev value and new value. But it shows 24 which is string, no math performed. How to
>   solve this, please?

```
           localStorage.quantity += parseInt(qty);
           alert(localStorage.quantity);
```

Answer (score 1):

*Local storage* store keys and values, where values are also strings. If you want to operate with a numeric value you need to get it from the *Local storage*, parse it to integer, perform the operation and store it again:

```
var value = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("value"));
value += 5;
localStorage.setItem("value", value);
```

Comment: how do I call /  alert the value then? Is it like: localStorage.setItem ?

Comment: @Keren `localStorage.getValue`

Comment: is it localStorage.getValue or localStorage.getValue("value")? Because localStorage.getValue("value") says 'undefined'

Comment: found it, its localStorage.getItem("value")..But it alerts Nan(latest quantity value). ANy idea why?

Comment: @Keren Now you need to use your mind and go ahead, you can't expect SO users to solve every part of your problem. I've given you a good sample of how to store and get values, if you get `NaN` is because you're not storing the data as you expect, or you're not using `parseInt` in the right way. Use the debugger, see the local storage items using the whole debugger.... After all, show your effort...

Comment: @Keren And sorry, it was `localStorage.getItem`. BTW, I doubt you've read my answer at all... I give you there a code of how to get and set items..........